# Get image attrib inside a div?

Tags: jquery, find

Say I have this:

```
 <div class='container'>
      <img src='image1' id='1' />
      <img src='image2' id='2' />
      ...
 </div>
 <div class='container'>
 </div>
```

Now, I when I click on the container, I want to get the id of the image inside it. If the container contains no image, it should pop up an error saying no images in the container. Otherwise, I would like to get a list of all the ids of the images inside.

Using jQuery, I have this:

```
 $('.container').click(function()
 {
      var images = $(this).find('img');
      if( images[0] == null ) { //no image found }
      else
      {
           // No idea what to do here :P
      }
 }
```

could someone please help me out here (I mean inside the else{} statement)? Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".container", function(){
    var img = $(this).find("img"), // select images inside .container
        len = img.length; // check if they exist
    if( len > 0 ){
        // images found, get id
        var attrID = img.first().attr("id"); // get id of first image
    } else {
        // images not found
    }
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/vuhAf/).

To get an array of the `id`s of all the images in the container:

```
var arr = []; // create array
if( len > 0 ){
    // images found, get id
    img.each(function(){ // run this for each image
        arr.push( $(this).attr("id") ); // push each image's id to the array
    });
} else {
    // images not found
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/vuhAf/1/).

And of course, what kind of a person would I be if I didn't give you an example with pure JS:

```
var elems = [].slice.call( document.getElementsByClassName("container") );
elems.forEach( function( elem ){
    elem.onclick = function(){
        var arr = [],
            imgs = [].slice.call( elem.getElementsByTagName("img") );
        if(imgs.length){
            imgs.forEach( function( img ){
                var attrID = img.id;
                arr.push(attrID);
            });
            alert(arr);
        } else {
            alert("No images found.");
        }
    };
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/Ajv3T/). A bit more complex, and I still recommend to use jQuery since it clears up all the cross browser mouse event madness.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var images = $(this).find('img');
    if(images.length === 0) {
        alert('no images found');
    }
    else {
        var ids = new Array;
        images.each(function(){
           ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        //ids now contains all the ids of img elements
        console.log(ids);
    }
```

Comment: I got that part! I mean what do I do for the rest? Inside the else{} statement!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.container').click(function() 
 {
 var images = $('img',this);
 if( $(images).length == 0 ) { 
        // No Image
    } 
    else       {   
        var ids = '';
        $(images).each(function(){
            ids = $(this).attr('id) + ",";
        });
        alert(ids);
    }  
}
```